# how do you pivot sql data without aggregating a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

I have the following output in a query.

```
SKILL                                              LEVEL          SCORERANGE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Stunts                                             LOW            0.0 - 4.0
Stunts                                             MED            3.0 - 7.0
Stunts                                             HI             6.0 - 10.0
Pyramids                                           LOW            0.0 - 4.0
Pyramids                                           MED            3.0 - 7.0
Pyramids                                           HI             6.0 - 10.0
Tosses                                             LOW            0.0 - 4.0
Tosses                                             MED            3.0 - 7.0
Tosses                                             HI             6.0 - 10.0
Standing Tumbling                                  LOW            0.0 - 4.0
Standing Tumbling                                  MED            3.0 - 7.0
Standing Tumbling                                  HI             6.0 - 10.0
Running Tumbling                                   LOW            0.0 - 4.0
Running Tumbling                                   MED            3.0 - 7.0
Running Tumbling                                   HI             6.0 - 10.0
Jumps                                              LOW            0.0 - 4.0
Jumps                                              MED            3.0 - 7.0
```

I want to PIVOT this data without aggregating anything.  So I want a result that shows only one row for each skill and pivots the LEVEL, something like this...

```
SKILL                                              LOWRANGE       MEDRANGE       HIRANGE 
Stunts                                             0.0 - 4.0      3.0 - 7.0      6.0 - 10.0
Pyramids                                           0.0 - 4.0      3.0 - 7.0      6.0 - 10.0
Tosses                                             0.0 - 4.0      3.0 - 7.0      6.0 - 10.0
Standing Tumbling                                  0.0 - 4.0      3.0 - 7.0      6.0 - 10.0
Running Tumbling                                   0.0 - 4.0      3.0 - 7.0      6.0 - 10.0
...
```

I do have a pretty good understanding of basic pivot syntax but I am struggling with this one because there is nothing to aggregate in the result set.

To give you something to try to fix for me...

```
SELECT SKILL, LOWRANGE, MEDRANGE, HIRANGE
FROM (SELECT SKILL, [LEVEL], SCORERANGE FROM ScoreRanges) ps
PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(SCORERANGE)  --THIS IS PROBABLY WRONG
        FOR SCORERANGE IN
        (
           --SOMETHING GOES HERE
        )
    ) as pvt
```

Thanks for your help.

Seth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know you will only have 1 row per `SKILL, LEVEL` combination you can use `Max` or `Min`

```
SELECT SKILL, [LOW] LOWRANGE, [MED] MEDRANGE, [HI] HIRANGE
FROM (SELECT SKILL, [LEVEL], SCORERANGE FROM ScoreRanges) ps
PIVOT (
        MAX(SCORERANGE) 
        FOR LEVEL IN ([LOW], [MED], [HI])
    ) as pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right

```
SELECT SKILL, LOW as LOWRANGE, MED as MEDRANGE, HI as HIRANGE
FROM (SELECT SKILL, [LEVEL], SCORERANGE FROM ScoreRanges) ps
PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(SCORERANGE)  
        FOR [LEVEL] IN
        (
           [LO], [HIGH], [MED]
        )
    ) as pvt
```

Here is an example you can run in the Adventureworks database, so you can play around with that also to see how `PIVOT` works

```
SELECT City, F AS Females, M AS Males
 FROM(
SELECT Gender,City
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
    INNER join HumanResources.EmployeeAddress AS ea
    ON e.EmployeeID = ea.EmployeeID
    INNER join Person.Address AS p
    ON ea.AddressID = p.AddressID
    ) AS pivTemp
PIVOT
(   COUNT(Gender)
    FOR Gender IN (F,M)
) AS pivTable
```

I also have nother PIVOT example here: [Three different ways of populating variables with configuration values in SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/three-different-ways-of-populating-varia)